# HTTP headers and error pages - NGINX

Tags: linux, nginx, server, http-headers, webserver

I am having a bit of trouble with the custom error pages in NGINX.
First, I tried this

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        if ( $request_method !~ (GET|POST) ) {
            error_page 418 = @not_supported;
            return 418;
        }
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x;
    }

    location @not_supported {
        return 501;
    }

    error_page 501 /some_page.html;
    location = /some_page.html {
        root html;
    }
}
```

If I am sending anything else other than `GET` or `POST`, I get a default error page that says `501 method is not implemented`, and the name and version of the server.
If the return is in the first location, then the server return the `some_page.html`.

After that, I tried to add `recursive_error_pages` on, which did help me by serving the custom error pages, but it changed the headers completely(added headers that i removed earlier).

Anyone knows how to make the server serve the custom pages, and keep the settings for the headers?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clearly specify with example as to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.
I moved all the configuration that I wanted to the location of the error, and it works like a charm.